# Getting Bad Access on defined function

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I keep getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on certain functions in a class. If I change the name of the function the error seems to go away...but I want to know why this is happening, because I happen to like the names that I'm giving my functions.

This is my h file-

```
@property(strong, nonatomic)NSString* month;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString* day;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString* description;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString* type;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString* venue;

@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView* imageView;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel* descriptionLabel;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel* venueLabel;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel* titleLabel;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel* typeLabel;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel* dateLabel;

@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel* monthLabel;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel* dayLabel;

-(void)setDate:(NSString*)month withDay:(NSString*)day;
-(void)setImage:(UIImage*)image;
```

These are my setters -

```
-(void)setDescription:(NSString *)description{
    self.description = description;
    self.descriptionLabel.text = description;
}

-(void)setTitle:(NSString *)title{
    self.title = title;
    self.titleLabel.text = title;
}

-(void)setType:(NSString *)type{
    self.type = type;
    self.typeLabel.text = type;
}


-(void)setVenue:(NSString *)venue{
    self.venue = venue;
    self.venueLabel.text = venue;
}

-(void)setDate:(NSString *)month withDay:(NSString *)day{
    self.month = month;
    self.day = day;
}

-(void)setImage:(UIImage*)image{
    self.imageView.image = image;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.monthLabel.text = self.month;
    self.dayLabel.text = self.day;
}
```

If I run this - I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on setTitle. If I change that to setEventTitle the error goes away, and I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on setVenue.

This is how I'm calling these functions-

```
-(UIView*)getEventResultView:(NSDictionary*)component{
EventViewController* eventVC = [[EventViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EventResultView" bundle:nil];
NSDictionary* dateDictionary =  someDate;
NSString* month= [self findMonth:dateDictionary];
[eventVC setDate:month withDay:someDay];
[eventVC setTitle: someTitle];
[eventVC setVenue: someVenue];
[eventVC setDescription:someDescription];

NSString* titleImageUrl = someUrl;
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSData *titleImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:titleImageUrl]];
    UIImage* titleImage = [UIImage imageWithData:titleImageData];
    [eventVC setImage: titleImage];
});

return eventVC.view;
```

}

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

You have an endless recursion:

```
-(void)setType:(NSString *)type
{
    self.type = type;
    …
}
```

It is here:

```
self.type = …;
```

is the short form of

```
[self setType:…];
```

So the method (there are no functions in your code) is called while it is executed.

Do this:

```
-(void)setType:(NSString *)type
{
    _type = type;
    …
}
```

Comment: ... and make sure you have ARC enabled.

Comment: … and make sure that you did not switch the MM to manual memory management? I'm pretty sure that he did not change the default. ;-)

Comment: Unless OP is working with an old code base, old templates, started with an old online example, or took some bad advice from one of the many sources of bad advice on the Internet... :)